# What is "A working copy merge source needs an explicit revision"?

Tags: svn

I checked out trunk and branch (let's call it B1) from my repository. I want to merge some revisions in trunk into B1, so I am doing this (pwd is B1):

`svn merge 6057:6068 ../trunk ./`

then SVN tells me:

`svn: E195002: A working copy merge source needs an explicit revision`

What does the error message mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks to me like you left off the `-r` flag.  So your command probably should be:

```
svn merge -r 6057:6058 ../trunk ./
```

You don't need to have both trunk and the branch checked out in order to the merge either.  You can use the repository relative URL syntax.  Assuming that trunk is at /trunk in your repo and current directory is root of working copy for branch B1 the following should work:

```
svn merge -r 6057:6058 ^/trunk
```

`^/` is replaced with the repository root URL.

If you're not deliberately trying to cherry-pick you may want to leave the revision off entirely, which will pull in all the changes from trunk to your branch.

Finally, save yourself some hassle and use `-c` instead of `-r` and then you can just do:

```
svn merge -c 6058 ^/trunk
```

You don't mention what version you're using so your mileage may vary with some of this if you're not on 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: These flags that are being bandied about (`-r`, `-c`) - what do they mean?

Comment: `-r` is short for `--revision` and lets you specify a range of revisions.  `-c` is short for `--change` and lets you specify a single revision (which prior to this option being added you had to specify using `--revision` with `-r ARG-1:ARG` where ARG is the revision you wanted).  You can read the documentation about this arguments to `svn merge` by doing `svn help merge`.